# Execution Flow in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following reques:

*Raise a custom exception handler KasayaError in the robe method if the argument type is not a String "Kasaya". It should return "Dharmaguptaka's Kasaya Robe" otherwise*

I have implemented the following function:

```
def robe(type)
  if type != 'Kasaya' 
    raise KasayaError("Invalid")
  end
  return "Dharmaguptaka's Kasaya Robe"
end
```

But when I ran it against rspec, I got the following results:

*should return 'Dharmaguptaka's Kasaya Robe' if type is 'Kasaya'
NoMethodError
undefined method `KasayaError' for #RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_157:0x000000029b1598*

My question is why the code broke?

In my mind, if the parameter is Kasaya, the return statement will be executed to return the result of the function. Am I correct?

Comment: The `type` you're sending into the function is not `"Kasaya"`, and it's attempting to raise an exception using a class that is not defined. Where are you defining `KasayaError`?

Comment: @meagar: No, it's attempting to raise an exception by calling the method `KasayaError`, there are no classes involved here.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes, I missed the lack of `.new`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if the parameter is not Kasaya, the return statement will be executed to return the result of the function. Am I correct?

No, that's the opposite of what your code is designed to do.

If the parameter is not `"Kasaya"`, then an exception is raised, and the `return` is never reached. This is the entire point of exceptions: They allow methods to "return" early, unwinding the call stack until a matching exception handler is found.

The only way the flow of execution reaches you `return` statement is if `type` **is** `"Kasaya"`. Then the condition `type != "Kasaya"` is false and the `raise` is never reached.

Comment: You are correct. Please see my edited version "In my mind, if the parameter is Kasaya, the return statement will be executed to return the result of the function. Am I correct?"